# Editing/Updating one of the results in a search query

Tags: php, mysql, html

I'm creating a page that searches for an item and then be able to edit/update it. I was able to do it when it returns just one result but when it gives me multiple results I could only edit the very last item. Below is my code:

```
.......
$dj =$_POST[djnum];
$sql= "SELECT * From dj WHERE datajack LIKE '$dj%'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
    //more code in here//

while ($info =mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

    // display the result
echo "<form action=\"dj_update.php\" method=\"POST\"><input type=\"hidden\" name=\"djnumber\" value=\"".$info['datajack']."\">";
echo "<tr><td>DJ ".$info['datajack']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$info['building']."&nbsp;</td>";
echo "<td>Rm ".$info['room']."&nbsp;</td>";
echo "<td>".$info['switch']."&nbsp;</td>";
echo "<td>".$info['port']."&nbsp;</td>";
echo "<td>".$info['notes']."&nbsp;</td>";
echo "<td style=\"text-align:center;\"><input type=\"Submit\" value=\"Edit\" ></td></tr>";      
}

// more code here //
```

Then this is the screen shot of the result:

[image]

The idea is the user should be able to click on "Edit" and be able to edit/update that particular item. But when I click any of the Edit button I could only edit the last item. What am I missing here? Is there an easier way to do this?

Thanks guys and Happy new year!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no form closing tag - it should be added after each "Edit" button.

Now, since forms are not closed, there are several hidden inputs with the same "djnumber" in each form, and I suppose, browser sends only one value - which is specified in your last row.

So, adding the following at the end of your loop:

```
echo "</form>";
```

should help.

Comment: Wow, That fixed it. how could I missed that. Thanks so much. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

What are the values for `datajack`?

If the values are `datajack1`, `datajack2` etc then a `LIKE` will return the first one every time, you need to make your query more specific.

```
$sql = "SELECT * From dj WHERE datajack id ' " . mysql_escape_string($id) . "' LIMIT 1";
```

I have changed the query to match one row and also use an id field, using `LIKE` in this situation is bad, you want to edit a specific row, not a row that is potentially `LIKE` the row you thought you were editing.

Note the use of `mysql_escape_string()` too to stop MySQL Injection techniques.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi, the datajack values varies. The values are like the ones you see in the screenshot. It's sometimes a 5 digit numbers followed by a letter or just numbers. Anyways, just like Kel said, I missed a closing tag for the form and it works now. Thanks.